# How can I disable segue by click on custom cell in UITableViewController without disable textField editing in this cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have custom cells with textfild.
For some cells I need disable segue by click and enable textfield for editing. I try so:

```
    if indexPath.row<tests.count{
       cell.themeTextField?.text = test.name
       cell.themeTextField.enabled=false
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false;   
    }
```

Segue is disabled, but then I can't type text in textField

Comment: enable the `themeTextField` in else and check.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr it doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an alternate,

Delete that segue from tableCell and create a new one from the `UITableViewController` (drag it from the objects navigator rather than the storyboard) to the next controller - and give it a name(eg : `DidSelectCellSegue`).

Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, perform the segue programmatically and conditionally.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    if conditionForPerformingSegueIsSatisfied {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DidSelectCellSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

and change `cellForRow` code to

```
if indexPath.row<tests.count{
   cell.themeTextField?.text = test.name
   cell.themeTextField.enabled=false
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
    cell.themeTextField.enabled = true;   
}
```